# Differentiation Math Limits

Tags: math, limits, differentiation

limit x-->3 2x^2 + 7x-15/x-3

What i Simplified

Step 1 : 2x^2 + 10x -3x -15 / x-3

Step 2 : 2x( x + 5)-3( x + 5)/x-3

Step 3 : (2x - 3)(x + 5)/x-3

but unable to move further.. im thinking either the question ix wrong or there ix some trick which im unable to understand
thanx in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths.

Comment: ys it ix about math actually i saw math tag in some question thats why i posted it here..

Comment: Questions about mathematics can be posted on http://math.stackexchange.com for example. Questions on this site must be related to computer programming. Besides, when you write 15/x-3, do you mean 15/x-3 or 15/(x-3)?

Comment: It's _is_, not _ix_... not sure if you simply mistyped, or if that's some horrible new textspeak word I haven't heard of...

Comment: no thix ix whole over x-3 mean (2x^2+7x-15)/(x-3)

Comment: ... not positive infinity.

Comment: @rummykhan this question belongs to here http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as x -> 3, the numerator goes to 3 * 8 = 24 and the denominator goes to 0, so the limit goes to +infinity if you approach 3 from the right, and -infinity if you approach 3 from the left

since you didn't specify which direction, the limit does not exist.

try graphing it: https://www.desmos.com/calculator